# Django - running manage.py produces fatal error for version.py: Not a git repository

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, apache, mod-wsgi

I have copied my `Django 1.4.3` app from one server to another. It is running using `mod_wsgi` daemon on the other server.

`mod_python` is installed, as verified by looking at `php.info()`. Python version is `2.7`, and Apache version is `2.4`.

I get the following error whenever I run `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
    logging_config_module = importlib.import_module(logging_config_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from mod_python.util import parse_qsl
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/version.py", line 3
    version = "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The `version.py` file has the following contents:

```
# THIS FILE IS AUTO-GENERATED BY setup.py

version = "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
3.5.0-"

# Some build-time constants:
HTTPD = "/usr/sbin/httpd"
HTTPD_VERSION = "2.4.6"
APR_VERSION = "1.4.8"
LIBEXECDIR = "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules"
SYSCONFDIR = ""
TEST_MOD_PYTHON_SO = "/usr/local/src/mod_python-3.5.0/src/mod_python.so" #NB: This is for test.py only
TESTHOME = "/usr/local/src/mod_python-3.5.0/test"
PYTHON_BIN = "/bin/python"
```

The app requires `python 2.7`, and I don't know how to reset `mod_python` to something that's compatible with version `2.7`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using mod_python at all. That hasn't been a supported deployment mechanism for Django for years.

Comment: @DanielRoseman as part of the work I am doing, I have to first move the application in its current state. We'll look into re-architecting next. Any thoughts on how to fix the issue?